# How to integrate aws-amplify authentication with react-admin?

Tags: authentication, aws-amplify, react-admin

I'm having problems integrating the authentication with aws amplify. First, I have this code in the authprovider of the admin-react, but I'm not sure how could I implement this with aws amplify.

```
import { AuthProvider } from 'react-admin';

const authProvider: AuthProvider = {
    login: ({ username }) => {
        localStorage.setItem('username', username);
        // accept all username/password combinations
        return Promise.resolve();
    },
    logout: () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('username');
        return Promise.resolve();
    },
    checkError: () => Promise.resolve(),
    checkAuth: () =>
        localStorage.getItem('username') ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject(),
    getPermissions: () => Promise.reject('Unknown method'),
    getIdentity: () =>
        Promise.resolve({
            id: 'user',
            fullName: 'Admin Name',
        }),
};

export default authProvider;
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following auth provider https://github.com/MrHertal/react-admin-amplify

Comment: Agreed, MrHertal package is a great starting point. If all you need is the authProvider portion you can grab just that file. We added a couple functions to ours like getIdentity.